# How to display a linked list in a struct in C

Tags: c, linked-list

```
typedef struct child_list {int count; char vo[100]; child_list*next;} child_list;
typedef struct parent_list
{ char vo[100];
child_list * head;
int count;
parent_list * next; } parent_list;
```

As you can see there are two structures. `child_list` is used to create a linked list. And this list will be stored in a linked list of parent list. My problem is to display the child list which in the `parent_list`.

My desire to get while displaying the linked list of `parent_list`:

This lists work with this logic. I already made append and other stuff.

For example if I enter `ab cd ab ja cd ab`

```
Word    Count    List

ab        3      cd->ja

cd        2      ab->ab

ja        1      cd
```

The problematic part is displaying `child_list` which is in the `parent_list` nodes(List column of output). I don't know my question is clear please ask for further info.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far, StackOverflow is an advice/help site not a "please write my code for me" site. If you show us what you have written so far, we can make suggestions and give ideas for next steps.

Comment: i'm not asking this. i'm asking about an idea not full code. So, pls save your judgements to yourself. I shared what should be known.

Comment: Please explain how your input is connected to your output. For example, I do not see where "cd->ja" comes from. What is the relationship between cd and ja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print the parent node with its child list you could do like follows

```
void print_node(parent_list *parent_node) {
    printf("%s\t%d\t", parent_node->vo, parent_node->count);

    child_list *child_node = parent_node->head;
    while (child_node != NULL) {
        printf("%s", child_node->vo);

        child_node = child_node->next;

        if (child_node != NULL) {
            printf("->");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```